# Excel 2010 - Subtotal of values with override fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, subtotal, vba

I have an excel sheet that needs to calculate the sum of values. Values can be in one of two fields, and if it is in the second one, I want to disregard the first one.

```
Row1: Default value | Override Value

Row2:       1       | 2

Row 3:      4       | no value entered

Row 4:      0       | 6


Subtotal of Values=12
```

If Override value is populated, then include that number, and not the Default Value in the subtotal. If Override value is not populated, then include the Default value in the Subtotal.

I need to use Subtotal 109 because I have fields that are sometimes hidden.

Is it possible to do this with a formula directly within the excel spreadsheet, and not **using and VBA code**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
=SUMIF(B1:B3,"",A1:A3) + SUMIF(B1:B3,"<>",B1:B3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be working. I will test this out further with my hidden fields to make sure it works there too since I use the Subtotal function

Comment: This is working even when I hide cells. Doesn't look like I need to worry about Subtotal here. Appreciate the help

Comment: Mark, My formula wont work with hidden rows. @lori_m 's formula is what you want :)

Comment: hmm, seems to be working for me, but that could be because of other calculations. I'll try them both out more extensively. Thanks for following up!!

Answer (score 2):

To account for hidden fields as well maybe try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A3)-ROW(A1),B1:B3<>"")))
```

(eg hiding second row gives 8)